# How can i catch and handle Error: EEXIST: file already exists, copyfile "somepath" "anotherpath" in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to change the name of file when i get duplicate files while performing copy operation in nodejs using fs module (right now the process exits with error, i want to execute file name change logic on error)

```
function copyFile(filePath,fileName){
fs.copyFileSync(filePath, 
    path.join(destination,fileName),fs.constants.COPYFILE_EXCL, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        fileName=  "0"+fileName; //changing the filename
        copyFile(filePath,fileName)
    }
    console.log(fileName+" copied");
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to check if `error.code === 'EEXIST'`.

Few notes:

- `copyFileSync` does not accept callback - it's a synchronous function
- You're using `path.join` incorrectly. This utility is used mainly to provide cross-platform paths (Unix - `/`, Windows - `\`). If you're concatenating it yourself with `/` there is no point to use `path.join` it will not work on non-unix systems anyway.
- There is a typo `filename` -> `fileName`
- You need two `fileName...` arguments for `copyFile` function (`source` and `destination`), because source file with prepended `0`-s not exists by the moment you're calling the function.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const destination = '/tmp/';

function copyFile(filePath, fileNameFrom, fileNameTo=fileNameFrom) {
  const from = path.join(filePath, fileNameFrom);
  const to = path.join(destination, fileNameTo);

  try {
    fs.copyFileSync(from, to, fs.constants.COPYFILE_EXCL);
    console.log(`${from} copied into ${to}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    if (error.code === 'EEXIST') {
      copyFile(filePath, fileNameFrom, '0' + fileNameTo);
    }   
  }
}


copyFile('/tmp/test', 'a.txt');
```

**Note**: do not forget to change `destination` variable

Comment: Is it that i can handle these kinds of error through try catch block or is there any other way to do this in nodejs..?

Comment: You could check if the file exists using [existsSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_existssync_path), but AFIAK it's not recommended due to race conditions

Comment: Add and `throw error` in your catch statement, so other kinds of error will be properly handle in the catch.